# (Pagination) Endless list from API - Android Recycler View

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I've created an endless list to deal with my pagination coming from an API, I get the next page data in a JSON and it getting parsed to my activity. But, my adapter is not updating with the new items. I've called notifyDataSetChanged and it's just not updating. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code below:

```
private void loadData(final boolean firstLoad) {

    mDataFactory.getPostFeed(mThreads.getId(), mCurrentPage, new PostFeedDataFactory.PostFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPostDataReceived(PostResponse response) {
            mData = response;
            if (mData.getItems() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mData.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    Posts singlePost = response.getItems().get(i);
                    postList.add(singlePost);
                }
                if (firstLoad) {
                    mIsLoading = false;
                    mData.getItems().clear();
                    mData.getItems().addAll(postList);


                    mEmoticonDataFactory.getEmoticonFeed(new EmoticonFeedDataFactory.EmoticonFeedDataFactoryCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEmoticonDataReceived(EmoticonResponse response) {
                            mEmoticon = response;
                            populateUIWithData();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onEmoticonDataFailed(Exception exception) {

                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    mIsLoading = false;
                    refreshPosts(postList);
                }

                if (mData.getItems().size() > 0) {
                    if (Integer.valueOf(mData.getTotalPosts()) >= response.getItems().size()) {
                        mCurrentPage++;
                    } else {
                        mIsLastPage = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostDataFailed(Exception exception) {
        }
    });


}

private void populateUIWithData() {

    mThreadText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.threadText);


    if (mThreads != null) {
        if (mThreads.getName() != null) {
            mThreadText.setText(mThreads.getName());
        }
    }
    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, mData, mEmoticon);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.setData(postList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(paginationListener);


}

private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener paginationListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!mIsLoading && !mIsLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
};

private void loadMoreItems() {
    mIsLoading = true;
    loadData(false);
}

private void refreshPosts(ArrayList<Posts> newObjects) {
    postList.addAll(newObjects);
    populateUIWithData();

}
```

Also, here is my adapter

**PostAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Posts posts = mPost.getItem(position);
    emoticons = mEmoticon.getItems();
    String message = null;
    String emoMessage = null;

    if (posts.getPost() != null) {
        if (posts.getPost().getMessage() != null) {
            message = posts.getPost().getMessage();
            emoMessage = message;


            if (emoticons != null) {
                for(Emoticons emoticon : this.emoticons) {
                    if (message.contains(emoticon.getEmoticon().getCode())) {
                        emoMessage = message.replaceAll(Constants.EMO_REGEX, emoticon.getEmoticon().getUrl());
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if (posts.getPost().getUsername() != null) {
            holder.mAuthorTextView.setText("Posted by: " + posts.getPost().getUsername());
        }

        if (posts.getPost().getHighlighting().equals("op")) {
            holder.mPostTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        }

        }

            holder.mPostTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(emoMessage, new Html.ImageGetter() {
                @Override
                public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                    Drawable d = null;
                    try {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        URL url = new URL(source);
                        InputStream is = url.openStream();
                        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), b);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return d;
                }
            }, new Html.TagHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader) {
                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strike") || tag.equals("s")) {
                        processStrike(opening, output);
                    }
                }
                private void processStrike(boolean opening, Editable output) {
                    int len = output.length();
                    if(opening) {
                        output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
                    } else {
                        Object obj = getLast(output, StrikethroughSpan.class);
                        int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

                        output.removeSpan(obj);

                        if (where != len) {
                            output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        }
                    }
                }

                private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
                    Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

                    if (objs.length == 0) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        for(int i = objs.length;i>0;i--) {
                            if(text.getSpanFlags(objs[i-1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                                return objs[i-1];
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                }

            }));

    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPost.getItems().size();
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Posts> array) {
    ArrayList<Posts> postList = this.mPost.getItems();
    postList = array;
}
```

Comment: Am on my smartphone so cannot grasp all your code, but have you considered one of the RecycleView extensions such as SuperRecycleView or UltimateRecycleView? They have build in features that enables loading more results as the user scrolls

Comment: No I haven't I did not know they even existed. I tried the EndlessRecyclerAdapter and attached my Adapter to it but that didn't seem to work either @cYrixmorten

Comment: I suggest you trim down the code snippet to a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it will help with focusing on the relevant parts

Comment: @AdamMichalik ah okay, I'll do that as soon as I get back on my machine. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Ok took a second look at your code and have some comments 1) `mIsLoading` is never set to false 2) I am not convinced that `((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount)` is a valid  condition for your case, just want you to ensure that it is called when you expect it to 3) Not sure about this one, but `refreshPosts` adds posts to `mData`, a List that is held by your Activity .. the RecyclerAdapters that I use keeps the data internally, so I am a bit concerned wheter it is able to detect changes in `mData`. The first load hands the data directly in `populateUIWithData()`

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks for taking a look. 1) mIsLoading, I noticed this and has been corrected (will update my code shortly) 2) it is being called when I want it to which I think is fine. 3) mData is getting the new items but it's not adding them to the adapter to then populate my recycler view, if that makes sense :) Again, all this help is really appreciated and I'm trying all suggestions

Comment: No problem :) If you do not manage to find a solution, then maybe also add your implementation of `PostAdapter`.

Comment: @cYrixmorten still can't get it to work, been trying all morning and for over the past week and just can't find out what is happening or what I'm doing wrong. Here's my updated code with also the onbind, getItemCount and a setData method I made. Please let me know if this is too much code as I don't know what would be relevant to help with the answer :)

Comment: Just a comment, but the ThreadPolicy thing is really hacky :-P you should create an AsyncTask or similar instead .. but looks like you are close to what I had in mind, though `setData()` looks broken, shouldn't it be doing `mPost.clear(); mPost.addAll(array)`? Assuming that `mPost` is a List ..

Comment: @cYrixmorten lol yeah I do, I was just trying to get things working :-P Thanks for the heads up. I missed that completely. Will implement and try! Thanks :) mPost.getItems() will return the list I need

Comment: Alright .. but forget about the optimisation for now.. though I might go with what @AdamMichalik suggests and cut the whole code to a bare minimum, just showing a single TextView in onBind etc. .. I know it is tedious, but makes it much easier to debug and avoid hiddens 'gems' that puts a stopper to what you are trying to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @cYrixmorten I changed my setData method to look like this

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Posts> array) {
    mPost.getItems().addAll(array);
}
```

I basically just forgot to update my adapter to populate for me... But I just want to say thank you to those who helped. :)

Comment: Then I would have to write an answer which you accept but no need, not here for the points :-P